# Python string formatting

Tags: python

I see you guys using

```
url = '"%s"' % url # This part

>>> url = "http://www.site.com/info.xx"
>>> print url
http://www.site.com/info.xx
>>> url = '"%s"' % url
>>> print url
"http://www.site.com/info.xx"
```

Is it advanced Python? Is there a tutorial for it? How can I learn about it?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225637/python-string-formatting

Comment: You've marked both questions as duplicates. Surely you'd mark only the latter (chronologically)

Comment: No, it's like twins.  Both should be destroyed.

Answer (score 17):

It's common string formatting, and very useful. It's analogous to C-style printf formatting. See [String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) in the Python.org docs. You can use multiple arguments like this:

```
"%3d\t%s" % (42, "the answer to ...")
```

Comment: The real answer is 43 but don't tell anyone.

Comment: @Janusz Lenar blasphemy, I will not flag you this time but big brother is keeping an eye on you now.

Comment: Url is broken => Correct Url https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings

Answer (score 8):

That line of code is using Python string formatting.  You can read up more on how to use it here: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Answer (score 0):

It is not advanced, you can use ' or " to define a string.

Check the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings).