# Inserting the same value multiple times when formatting a string

Tags: python, string, format

I have a string of this form

```
s='arbit'
string='%s hello world %s hello world %s' %(s,s,s)
```

All the %s in string have the same value (i.e. s).
Is there a better way of writing this? (Rather than listing out s three times)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543399/python-string-formatting

Comment: This `%` string operator will be "deprecated on Python 3.1 and removed later at some time" http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#pep-3101-a-new-approach-to-string-formatting now I wonder what is the most advised way for both version compatibility and security.

Comment: @Cawas I know this is pretty late, but I like using `str.format()`. Ex.: `query = "SELECT * FROM {named_arg}"; query.format(**kwargs)`, where `query` is the format string and `kwargs` is a dictionary with keys matching the `named_arg`s in the format string.

Comment: @Edwin not too late. So, basically same thing from the accepted answer, from Adam, i see.

Comment: @Cawas Yeah, except Adam used tuple notation, where `{0}`, `{1}`, `{2}` and so on correspond to tuple indices `0`, `1`, and `2`, respectively. Alternatively, it's also possible to name the args (like `{named_arg}`) and set each one in the format method, like so: `'Hi {fname} {lname}!'.format(fname='John', lname='Doe')`

Comment: You can mix and match between number format (`{0}`) and name format (`{named_args}`), but I'd recommend that you just stick to one or the other, since A) I don't know the consequences of mixing and matching, and B) you won't have to do complicated mental gymnastics and it makes it easier to read, debug, and extend code later on.

Comment: @bignose You have marked both questions duplicates of one another its like http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&rlz=&q=recursio#q=recursion&spell=1&sa=X&ei=1IZmUcepBMLYrQeCr4CACQ&ved=0CCoQBSgA&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45107431,d.bmk&fp=722769dafe3ca9b1&biw=1366&bih=643

Comment: @Edwin I know this is pretty late, but that is how SQL injection happens.  I hope that isn't something you ever do in production code.

Answer (score 235, accepted):

You can use [advanced string formatting](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/), available in Python 2.6 and Python 3.x:

```
incoming = 'arbit'
result = '{0} hello world {0} hello world {0}'.format(incoming)
```

Comment: ~my personal preference, go for kwargs style `result = '{st} hello world {st} hello world {st}'.format(st=incoming)`

Answer (score 50):

```
incoming = 'arbit'
result = '%(s)s hello world %(s)s hello world %(s)s' % {'s': incoming}
```

You may like to have a read of this to get an understanding: [String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

Comment: Nice. Had forgotten about this. locals() will do as well.

Comment: @Goutham: Adam Rosenfield's answer might be better if you're Python version is up to date.

Comment: It is actually. Iam still getting used to the new string formatting operations.

Comment: even better, you can multuply the base string: '%(s)s hello world '*3 % {'s': 'asdad'}

Comment: s is missleading as variable name here and don't forget that the 's' or another formatting option (d, d03, ...) is manadatory after the %(<field-name>) pattern. '%(s) hello' doesn't work  '%(s)s hello' does.

Answer (score 18):

You can use the dictionary type of formatting:

```
s='arbit'
string='%(key)s hello world %(key)s hello world %(key)s' % {'key': s,}
```

Answer (score 13):

Depends on what you mean by better. This works if your goal is removal of redundancy.

```
s='foo'
string='%s bar baz %s bar baz %s bar baz' % (3*(s,))
```

Answer (score 4):

## Fstrings

If you are using `Python 3.6+` you can make use of the new so called `f-strings` which stands for formatted strings and it can be used by adding the character `f` at the beginning of a string to identify this as an [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

```
price = 123
name = "Jerry"
print(f"{name}!!, {price} is much, isn't {price} a lot? {name}!")
>Jerry!!, 123 is much, isn't 123 a lot? Jerry!
```

> The main benefits of using f-strings is that they are more readable, can be faster, and offer better performance:

Source Pandas for Everyone: Python Data Analysis, By Daniel Y. Chen

## Benchmarks

No doubt that the new `f-strings` are more readable, as you don't have to remap the strings, but is it faster though as stated in the aformentioned quote?

```
price = 123
name = "Jerry"

def new():
    x = f"{name}!!, {price} is much, isn't {price} a lot? {name}!"


def old():
    x = "{1}!!, {0} is much, isn't {0} a lot? {1}!".format(price, name)

import timeit
print(timeit.timeit('new()', setup='from __main__ import new', number=10**7))
print(timeit.timeit('old()', setup='from __main__ import old', number=10**7))
> 3.8741058271543776  #new
> 5.861819514350163   #old
```

Running 10 Million test's it seems that the new `f-strings` are actually faster in mapping.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s1 ='arbit'
>>> s2 = 'hello world '.join( [s]*3 )
>>> print s2
arbit hello world arbit hello world arbit
```

Comment: I guess that the example in the question was not about 'hello world' repeated, but a real template with no duplication. That's why I downvoted.