# Python - f.write 1 arguments, 2 given

Tags: python

```
import os
from os import stat
from pwd import getpwuid

searchFolder = raw_input("Type in the directory you wish to search e.g \n /Users/bubble/Desktop/ \n\n\n")
resultsTxtLocation = raw_input("FIBS saves the results in a txt file. Where would you like to save results.txt? \nMust look like this: /users/bubble/desktop/workfile.txt \n\n\n") 

with open(resultsTxtLocation,'w') as f:
    f.write('You searched the following directory: \n' + searchFolder + '\n\n\n')
    f.write('Results for custom search: \n\n\n')
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(searchFolder):
            for file in files:
                    pathName = os.path.join(root,file)
                    print pathName
                    print os.path.getsize(pathName)
                    print
                    print stat(searchFolder).st_uid
                    print getpwuid(stat(searchFolder).st_uid).pw_name
                    f.write('UID: \n'.format(stat(searchFolder).st_uid))
                    f.write('{}\n'.format(pathName))
                    f.write('Size in Bytes: {}\n\n'.format(os.path.getsize(pathName)))
```

I'm having trouble with this line:

```
f.write('UID: \n'.format(stat(searchFolder).st_uid))
```

I don't know what '{}\n'.format does, but someone suggested it in a previous question, so I thought it'd work here, but it doesn't.

Inside the output text file, I just get the following:

UID: 
/Users/bubble/Desktop/Plot 2.docx
Size in Bytes: 110549

But it should say: UID: 501

How can I make the f.write understand two arguments and write it into the txt file?

many thanks

Comment: You forgot the `{}` in the string you're passing to `.write()`.

Comment: Thanks, I added that and it works. What exactly is {} doing?? How come it works with those simple brackets??

Comment: It's the placeholder for the parameter in `.format()` (check out [format string syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings)).

Comment: Thanks Tim, very much appreciated. I'll check that link out now.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote the answers given below. You now have enough reputation to do so :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'UID: {}\n'.format(stat(searchFolder).st_uid)`. If there is no `{}`, it just returns `{}: \n`.

This is string format. The `{}` represents a replacement fields. You may read the [doc](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Comment: Thank you for your time & help zhangyangyu

Answer (score 2):

change

```
f.write('UID: \n'.format(stat(searchFolder).st_uid))
f.write('{}\n'.format(pathName))
f.write('Size in Bytes: {}\n\n'.format(os.path.getsize(pathName)))
```

into

```
f.write('UID: {0}\n'.format(stat(searchFolder).st_uid))
f.write('{0}\n'.format(pathName))
f.write('Size in Bytes: {0}\n\n'.format(os.path.getsize(pathName)))
```

[Look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225637/python-string-formatting) and into [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) to learn about string formatting.