# Python error unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, if-statement, return-value

here is my code:

```
def naame(value, suit):
    if suit == ("D"):
            suit ==  ("Dimnd")
    return  (value + " of " +suit)
```

So I think where the problem lies is when I add '+' too it... but still I have no idea on how to go about doing this...

I still fairly new at python. Please help me

Comment: so is "value" supposed to be an int? if so, you want to pass in str(value)

Comment: The line `suit == "Dimnd"` should be `suit = "Dimnd"`.  `==` test equality, it does not do assignment.

Comment: Also, in Python, putting extra parentheses where they aren't needed is usually considered bad style. A reader will waste time trying to figure out what you were _trying_ to do (create a tuple? override operator precedence? call a function?), and maybe even come to the wrong conclusion (e.g., write an irrelevant and unhelpful answer like "If you want that to be a tuple, you have to write `("Dimnd", )`"). Just write `if suit == "D":`, `suit = "Dimnd"`, and `return value + " of " + suit`.

Answer (score 5):

That error (properly called a `TypeError`) can only be generated if `value` is an integer.  Furthermore, in Python, you cannot put integers and strings together with `+`.

To fix your problem, make `value` a string:

```
return (str(value) + " of " + suit)
```

By putting `value` in [`str()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#str), it is converted to its string representation.  See an example below:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>
>>> a = str(a)
>>> type(a)
<type 'str'>
>>>
```

In addition to the solution I gave above, there are also some other methods of doing what you want:

```
return "%i of %s" % (value, suit)

return "{0} of {1}".format(value, suit)
```

If you want a reference concerning these last two methods, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225637/python-string-formatting).

Regardless of which one you choose, the core concept here is you can't combine integers and strings.  All three methods make `value` a string before using it.