# Cleanest way to query a DataFrame on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with 3 columns that represent the same data (the name of a person). The columns are `Username`,  `BuyerName`, `TravelerName`. In some cases, these three columns can share the same value (the username is the same person who bought a ticket and used it to travel, for instance), and I want to exclude/filter these cases. Here is my current working code:

```py
def filter_df(df, user_name):
   filtered_df = df.query(f'Username != "{user_name}" & BuyerName != "{user_name}" & TravelerName != "{user_name}")
   return filtered_df
```

I'd like to know if there is a cleverer way of doing this query instead of just repeating the same value over and over the columns.

Comment: `df[df[['Username','BuyerName','TravelName']].ne(user_name).all(1)]`.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15315452/6340496) provides a clean/readable/standard method (from a pandas perspective).  Although, it must be said that @QuangHoang comment above is beautiful!

Comment: Thank you! A question that extends the original problem, can this solution be applied as well to the case of filtering rows when `user_name` appears at least once among the three columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `.format()`:

```py
def filter_df(df, user_name):
   return df.query('Username != "{0}" & BuyerName != "{0}" & TravelerName != "{0}"'.format(user_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use advanced string formatting as explained here, so you don't have to repeat the user_name variable name over and over again: [Inserting the same value multiple times when formatting a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225637/inserting-the-same-value-multiple-times-when-formatting-a-string)