# format printing

Tags: python, printing

How to format printing stmt in python?

```
print"---------------------------------"

print"client:mount-point:logfile:status"

print"---------------------------------"

print clientname,mntpt,logfile,status
```

Currently it prints something like this :

```
---------------------------------

client:mount-point:logfile:status

---------------------------------

client01 : /some/path/mnt/1007/1 : /export/something/laks/specs_dir/log/client1/gc.log:running
```

How to make this output better?. Any suggestions

Comment: It works.  What's the problem?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543399/python-string-formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at string formatting : http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesseq-strings.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to format a table, consider using other software for table formatting.

As an example, you can produce HTML with the `print` statements and view the table with a browser. Another option is to generate [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#module-csv) data to be viewed using a spreadsheet program.

Answer (score 0):

Stick some tab spacing in for a start?

```
'\t'
```