# Integer to Hexadecimal Conversion in Python

Tags: python, int, hex

```
a = 1
print hex(a)
```

The above gives me the output: `0x1`

How do I get the output as `0x01` instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python string formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543399/python-string-formatting)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) :

```
>>> a = 1
>>> '{0:02x}'.format(a)
'01'
>>> '0x{0:02x}'.format(a)
'0x01'
```

Comment: This should be preferred over the `%` methods (aka old-style formatting).

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> format(1, '#04x') 
'0x01'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print "0x%02x"%a
```

`x` as a format means *"print as hex"*.
`02` means *"pad with zeroes to two characters"*.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
print "0x%02x" % a
```

It's a little hairy, so let me break it down:

The first two characters, "0x" are literally printed. Python just spits them out verbatim.

The % tells python that a formatting sequence follows.
The 0 tells the formatter that it should fill in any leading space with zeroes and the 2 tells it to use at least two columns to do it. The x is the end of the formatting sequence and indicates the type - hexidecimal.

If you wanted to print "0x00001", you'd use "0x%05x", etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format):

```
>>> "0x"+format(1, "02x")
'0x01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is f-string variant for Python 3.6+:

```py
a = 1
print(f"{a:0>2x}")
```

Explanation of string formatting:

- `:`: format specifier
- `0`: fill (with `0`)
- `>`: right-align field
- `2`: width
- `x`: `hex` type

Source: [6.1.3.1 Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)