# PythonHEX are in 0x2 format.... how to get 0x02?

Tags: python, hex

I have a decimal and write it with

```
hex(dezimal)
```

to the hex number. But I miss the 0, when i format digits 0-9

it should look like `0x09` and it looks `0x9`

What can I do?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integer to Hexadecimal Conversion in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28650857/integer-to-hexadecimal-conversion-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You had to modify the result by your own function:

```
def pad_hex(s):
    return '0x' + s[2:].zfill(2)

print(pad_hex(hex(9)))
```

> Output: 0x09

Answer (score 0):

If you need only to output a single byte (i.e. values from 0..255),

```python
"{0:#04x}".format(dezimal)
```

gives hex output with 0x prefix.

The field length (4) applies to the entire output, i.e. including the 0x prefix. If you need variable length, then @atline's solution is more flexible.