# Modbus client script read a sensor value

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus

I have a Modbus server setup on a LAN with IP address 192.168.0.111 and Modbus map is this snip below where I am trying read the sensor highlighted yellow:

[image]

Can someone give me a tip on how to run a Modbus client script and read the sensor value?

```
from pymodbus.client import ModbusTcpClient

client = ModbusTcpClient('192.168.0.111')
result = client.read_coils(30500,1)
print(result.bits[0])

client.close()
```

This will error out:

```
print(result.bits[0])
AttributeError: 'ExceptionResponse' object has no attribute 'bits'
```

Experimenting a bit and changing the print to `print(result)` this will return without an exception

```
Exception Response(129, 1, IllegalFunction)
```

Comment: It might be the case that the first address digit indicates the Modbus function code. Try `client.read_holding_registers(500, 2, unit=1)`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment...same thing - `AttributeError: 'ExceptionResponse' object has no attribute 'bits'`

Comment: Its one of these stand alone electrical meters: https://www.egauge.net/commercial-energy-monitor/

Comment: One thing I notice is when I use: `result = client.read_input_registers(500, 2, unit=1)
print(result)` this doesnt return an `ExceptionResponse` from the device...this will just print `ReadInputRegistersResponse (2)`

Comment: But I still cant get around the `print(result.bits[0])
AttributeError: 'ReadInputRegistersResponse' object has no attribute 'bits'`

Comment: What does `print result.registers` return?

Comment: If I do `result = client.read_input_registers(500,2,units=1)` and a `print(result.registers)` this returns  `[17139, 29148]`

Comment: the value I am looking for is 120 volts...and what returns makes no sense to me. What is also shown in the screenshot I posted is this which also makes no sense to me `Divide returned value by indicated Denominator to get quantity with the indicated unit`

Comment: Combine the two values to a 32 bit float, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59883083/convert-two-raw-values-to-32-bit-ieee-floating-point-number

Comment: Holy smokes that works....I still have to wrap my head around this but I get `123.0594253540039` which is definitely voltage.  if you posted an answer I would hit the green check box

Comment: I postend an answer but feel free to post something and ill give you the green check box points

Answer (score 1):

In the chat for this question...this [overstackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59883083/convert-two-raw-values-to-32-bit-ieee-floating-point-number) question was referenced. Complete answer:

```
from pymodbus.client import ModbusTcpClient
from pymodbus.constants import Endian
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder


client = ModbusTcpClient('192.168.0.111')
result = client.read_input_registers(500,2,units=1)
print(result.registers)
decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(result.registers, byteorder=Endian.Big)
print(decoder.decode_32bit_float())
client.close()
```